# TFS 2013 SSRS Test Points

Tags: reporting-services, tfs, report

I am working with TFS 2013 and generating reports with SSRS however I have benn tasked with creating a detailed report showing all steps and acceptance criteria for each test case and list the available parameters. I have searched and searched the web and have not found any examples that show the test steps.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In most instances the **Test Steps** fields are not set to reportable by default so they are not populated in normal reporting databases.  You'll need to set them to reportable or create a new data source targeting your TFS transaction databases instead of the Warehouse/Cube databases.

It is **not** recommended you target transaction databases with reports since this can affect performance of TFS when reports are run.  Especially a field like Test Steps since it might need to pull a lot of data at once.

Use the **witadmin** command to change the reportability of the Test Steps field.  Using detail will only put the information in your Warehouse while the detail option will put it into the Warehouse and the Cube.  Where you want it depends on how you write your reports.  Once set the reportability type can only be changed in limited ways, so please keep this in mind when deciding how you want it set.

```
witadmin changefield n:<nameOfFieldToChange> /collection:http://yourcollectionURL:8080/tfs/YourCollectionName /reportingtype:<dimension,detail>
```

[See the reportable attributes section for details.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194980.aspx)